# Average decrease of a random number in "subtracting every prime by one in factorization"

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, limits, asymptotics

> **Question**: Consider $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_\omega^{\alpha_\omega}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. Define $a(n)=(p_1-1)^{\alpha_1}\cdots (p_\omega-1)^{\alpha_\omega}$ and $A(n)=\sum_{k\le n}a(k)$. Calculate the value of $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A(n)}{n^2/2}.$$ Hence deduce the average order of $a(n)$.

**Quick Result**
$a$ is a completely multiplicative function with $a(p)=p-1$.
**Attempt**
It is not hard to see $a$ is the Dirichlet inverse of $\mu\cdot\varphi$, where $\cdot$ denotes the ordinary multiplication. Hence, the Dirichlet generating function of $a$ is $$\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)\varphi(n)}{n^s}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}(p-1)}$$
But the Dirichlet g.f. can be also written as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a(n)}{n^s}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{A(n) \left( \frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{\left( n+1 \right) ^s} \right)}=1+s\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{A( x )}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x}$$
Apply inverse Mellin transform, for $x>1$,$$A( x ) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{z}\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{a(n)}{n^z}} -1 \right) \text{d}t},\ (z=\sigma +it,\ \sigma>2)
\\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{x^z}{z} \prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-z}( p-1 )} \mathrm{d}t}-1
$$
So the next thing may be investigating $\prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-z}\ ( p-1 )}$, but I am not able to do that.
**Computational Result**
Mathematica suggests that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A(n)}{n^2}\approx0.25727$ and even $A(n)=Cn^2+o(n\ln n)$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: If you take the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean (i.e. $B(n)=\exp\left(\sum_{k\le n}\log a(k)\right)$), the random model of the primes suggests that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{B(n)}{n^2}=\frac12\exp\left(\sum_p\frac{\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)}{p-1}\right)\approx0.1819$. Of course the geometric mean is lower than the arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "But the Dirichlet g.f. can also be written as" you have a spurious $1$,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} A(n)\biggl(\frac{1}{n^s} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^s}\biggr) = s \int_1^{\infty} \frac{A(x)}{x^{s+1}}\,dx\,.$$
That doesn't affect the asymptotics of course.

If we look at the Euler product, we see that
$$F(s) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1 - \frac{p-1}{p^s}}$$
is very close to $\zeta(s-1)$, hence it is promising to write $F(s) = \zeta(s-1)\cdot H(s)$, where
$$H(s) = \prod_p \frac{1 - \frac{p}{p^s}}{1 - \frac{p-1}{p^s}} = \prod_p\frac{1 - \frac{p-1}{p^s} - \frac{1}{p^s}}{1 - \frac{p-1}{p^s}} = \prod_p\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p^s - p + 1}\biggr)\,.$$
This product converges absolutely for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ and hence the principal part of $F(s)$ at the pole $s = 2$ is
$$\frac{H(2)}{s-2}\,.$$
Now $A(x) = \frac{C}{2}x^2 + O(x^{2 - \varepsilon})$ implies that the principal part of $F(s)$ at $s = 2$ is the principal part of
$$\frac{Cs}{2}\int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{s-1}} = \frac{Cs}{2(s-2)} = \frac{C}{s-2} + \frac{C}{2}$$
at $s = 2$, i.e. $C = H(2)$.

We can evaluate $H(2)$ in closed form:
\begin{align}
H(2) &= \prod_p \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p^2-p+1}\biggr) \\
&= \prod_p \frac{p(p-1)}{p^2-p+1} \\
&= \prod_p \frac{p(p-1)(p+1)}{p^3+1} \\
&= \prod_p \frac{p(p^2-1)(p^3-1)}{p^6-1} \\
&= \prod_p \frac{(1 - p^{-2})(1 - p^{-3})}{1 - p^{-6}} \\
&= \frac{\zeta(6)}{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)} \\
&= \frac{2\pi^4}{315\zeta(3)} \\
&\approx 0.5145\,.
\end{align}
We have not proved that indeed $A(x) = \frac{C}{2}x^2 + O(x^{2-\varepsilon})$, hence we have not yet proved that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{A(n)}{n^2/2} = H(2)\,,$$
and that thus the average order of $a(n)$ is $H(2)\cdot n$. This however follows either by Tauberian theorems ($A$ is monotonic, so a variant of the Wiener–Ikehara theorem is applicable) or by estimates for $\zeta(s-1)$ near the line $\operatorname{Re} s = 2$ and an argument similar to Landau's proof of the prime number theorem. Since $F(s)$ is, except for the pole at $s = 2$, holomorphic in the half-plane $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ and decent estimates for $\lvert\zeta(s)\rvert$ in the critical strip are known, we can in this way establish $A(x) = \frac{1}{2}H(2)x^2 + O(x^{2-\varepsilon})$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$. Getting the remainder term to $O(x^{1+\varepsilon})$ or possibly even $O(x\log x)$ requires more careful estimates.

Comment: The numerical value is actually

$$
\frac{2\pi^4}{315\zeta(3)}\approx0.5145\;,
$$

in agreement with the result given in the question.

Comment: Oops, I've divided by $\zeta(6)$ instead of $\zeta(3)$. Embarrassing.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a somewhat more pedestrian approach:

For a given prime $p$, a proportion $\frac{p-1}{p^{k+1}}$ of integers have exactly $k$ factors of $p$, and for these integers $a(n)$ is reduced by a factor $\left(\frac{p-1}p\right)^k$. Thus the average reduction is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{p-1}{p^{k+1}}\left(\frac{p-1}p\right)^k
&=&
\frac{p-1}p\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{p-1}{p^2}\right)^k
\\
&=&
\frac{p-1}p\frac1{1-\frac{p-1}{p^2}}
\\
&=&
\frac{p^2-p}{p^2-p+1}
\\
&=&
\left(1+\frac1{p(p-1)}\right)^{-1}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $a(n)$ is completely multiplicative, the reductions due to different primes are multiplied, so the overall reduction factor, and thus the desired limit, is, as derived in Daniel Fischer’s answer, the reciprocal of [Landau’s totient constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_summatory_function#The_summatory_of_reciprocal_totient_function)

$$
\prod_p\left(1+\frac1{p(p-1)}\right)=\frac{315}{2\pi^4}\zeta(3)\approx1.943596\;.
$$